# Click element only working Intermittently

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have this strange issue. The purpose of the test is to login and click an element. The login test seems to work consistently but clicking an element after login seems to work intermittently. If I run the test 10 times, it seem to work 4 times.

```
driver.get("SomeWebsite");
driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[2]/a")).click(); 
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id*='textfield']")).sendKeys("someemail");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type*='password']")).sendKeys("password");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[3]/em/button")).click();
```

The codes seem to work fine till this point. However, the code below is the one I am having the issue.

```
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("header")));


driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li/a")).click(); // corresponding HTML <a href="#!mainmenu">Menu</a>
```

Comment: you can check for presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'#!mainmenu')]")) and then try out myDynamicElement.click().

Comment: @VivekSingh. Thanks. However, this approach is this case does not seem to be stable and only works intermittently.

Comment: can u plz try with `elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'#!mainmenu')]"))`

Comment: Same issue. So far thread.sleep seems to be working consistently. It is really strange.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options for this.

**1**)Seems you are overdoing the pageLoadTimeouts, try using implicit wait and set it once when driver loads up as follows

```
driver.get("SomeWebsite");
driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[2]/a")).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id*='textfield']")).sendKeys("someemail");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type*='password']")).sendKeys("password");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[3]/em/button")).click();
```

You could tweak the implicit wait to different values for the sake of stability. Try giving a few trial runs with 40 or 20 seconds as well.

**2**)Though this is not a perfect solution but you could halt the execution for some time using Raw wait or **Thread.Sleep** before you click on the element giving you trouble this includes a magic number but it's known to work 9 out of 10 times.

Comment: Thanks. I have ran the test about 20 times using thread.sleep. This seems to work. However, every other approach like wait for the element to be visible, implicit wait seems to be working intermittently. There has to be a robust way than using sleep.thread